# Simple check all not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to include a check all for my todo list, but once I hit `toggleAll()` it gets unchecked right away, plus it unchecks whichever one is already checked.

I really couldn't figure out why this behavior, perhaps some other things in the page are interfearing. A simple version of what I have included here is in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TKVH6/487/ and it is working.

```
<section id="main">
                <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll" ng-click="toggleAll()">
                <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
                <ul id="todo-list">
                    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted=='true'}" class="editing">
                        <div class="view" >
                            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" ng-click="complete(todo)" ng-model="todo.isCompleted" ng-checked="todo.isCompleted" ng-true-value="'true'"  ng-false-value="'false'">
                            <label ng-hide="isEditing" ng-dblclick="isEditing = !isEditing">{{todo.title}}</label>
                            <button class="destroy" ng-click="remove(todo)"></button>
                        </div>
                        <input class="edit" ng-show="isEditing" ng-model="todo.title" ng-blur="isEditing = !isEditing;edit(todo);">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.toggleAll = function () {
    if ($scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (todo) {
        todo.isCompleted = $scope.selectedAll;
    });
};
```

**EDIT 1**

```
$scope.toggleAll = function() {
    for(i in $scope.todos) {
        $scope.todos[i].isCompleted = $scope.checkAll;
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try removing {{}} from todo.isCompleted first, now update if you still experience any issues and I will try helping you.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same way. Check my EDIT 1, just cleaned up toggleAll(), this way it unchecks all boxes, but the master stays checked.

Comment: I was talking about the curly brackets here: ng-checked="{{todo.isCompleted}}" your removed them right? just making sure because you didn't edit this.

Comment: Yes I did, I updated it now.

Comment: With my new method toggleAll() it always unchecks them all, either you checkAll or uncheckAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Treating  the boolean as string solved it. That is because the server saves the boolean values as strings.

```
$scope.toggleAll = function() {
    for(i in $scope.todos) {
        $scope.todos[i].isCompleted = "" + $scope.checkAll;
    }
};
```

At this point `ng-checked="{{todo.isCompleted}}` needs to be back since it is not a boolean.